# Vectorisation of string matching

Tags: python, pandas

Question:
Is it possible to vectorise the string matching of two DataFrames/Series?

Concept:
I have two DataFrames (df_address, df_world_city):

1. df_address: Contains an column with address data (eg. "Sherlock Str.; Paris;")
2. df_world_city: Contains a column with city names and the corresponding country ("FRA", "Paris")

I go through each of address and try to match against all cities, to find out which city is mentioned in the address and add the corresponding country to it. The matched cities are saved in a list and the list is the value of dictionary with the country as a key ( {'FRA': ['Paris']}).

At the moment I am using mostly for-loops to go through the address and cities to match them. With multiprocessing (48 process) and a lot of data (df_address: 160,000 rows; df_wordl_city: 2,200,000 rows) it takes about 4-5 days.

```
def regex_city_matching(target, location):

    if type(target) != str or type(location) != str or len(target) <= 3:
        # Skip NaN and to short cities
        return False
    # Match city only as full word, not a substring of another word
    pattern = re.compile('(^|[\W])' + re.escape(target) + '($|[\W])', re.IGNORECASE)
    result = re.search(pattern, location)
    if result:
        return True
    return False


def city_matching_no_country_multi_dict_simple(self, df_world_city, df_address):

 col_names = ['node_id', 'name', 'city_iso']
 df_matched_city_no_country = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

 for index_city in df_world_city.index:
     # Iterate over each city
     w_city = df_world_city.at[index_city, 'city']
     if type(w_city) != str or len(w_city) <= 3:
         # Skip NaN and to short cities
         continue

     w_country = df_world_city.at[index_city, 'iso']

     for ind_address in df_address.index:
         if self.regex_city_matching(w_city, df_address.at[ind_address, 'name']):
             node_id = df_address.at[ind_address, 'node_id']
             address = df_address.at[ind_address, 'name']
             if (df_matched_city_no_country['node_id'] == node_id).any():
                 # append new city / country
                 ind_append_address = df_matched_city_no_country.loc[df_matched_city_no_country.node_id == node_id].index[0]
                          if w_country in df_matched_city_no_country.at[ind_append_address, 'city_iso']:
                     # Country in dictionary
                     df_matched_city_no_country.at[ind_append_address, 'city_iso'][w_country].append(w_city)
                 else:
                     # Country not in dictionary
                     df_matched_city_no_country.at[ind_append_address, 'city_iso'][w_country] = [w_city]
             else:
                 # add new address with city / country
                 dict_iso_city = {w_country: [w_city]}
                 df_matched_city_no_country = df_matched_city_no_country.append(
                     {'node_id': node_id, 'name': address, 'city_iso': dict_iso_city},
                     ignore_index=True)

return df_matched_city_no_country
```

EDIT:
Thank you to @lenik! The matching with a set of cities is much more efficient and is done pretty fast.

But it was not completely implemented, as the test showed that the amount of false-positives is to high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an inverse dictionary with `{ 'city' : 'COUNTRY', }`, so you don't have to loop through, just have a direct access in the constant (O(1)) time.

Besides that I would make a `set()` of known cities, so I don't have to loop through anything, just a quick lookup, and I know if this city is unknown.

Finally, I would simplify addresses parsing without using very expensive regex, convert all characters to upper or lower case, replace non-alphabetic characters with spaces and just `.split()` to get a list of words instead of what you're doing right now.

Once you made all these changes, processing 160k addresses with 2M known cities should take maybe 10-15 seconds.

Please, tell me if you need code samples?

Comment: Thank you! -- 1. Why reverse the dict? I don't really loop through it?! -- 2. A set of cities sounds good, but: I have some cities multiple times in different countries and how do I know why country is the city from? -- 3. Split sounds good, but could you provide some examples, how I would go through the list to match against my cities? Thanks again :)

Comment: @user3388671 how do you deal with same cities in different countries right now ?

Comment: I treat each city as unique, because in the other column 'iso' is the country code. So if a city matches, I use the index of the city to assign the country code to w_country. Could you provide code sample how to iterate efficiently over the splitted address and check in the set_world_city.

Comment: @user3388671 if you have the country code, why you need to search cities, just get a country by the country code, no matter what city?

Comment: The idea is to get the country and the city out of the data. The address with explicit country name I got pretty easy and fast. Next step was to get the city for this address, because I only matched against cities from matched countries. Last step and the idea of the current function is to get the city from the data and identify based on the match city the country of the address, even if it is not written out. But the amount of false-positive hits is extreme and the results are usable.

Comment: @user3388671 that's a very nice idea. you might need a fuzzy matching, which includes not only a city, but probably a street or some other part of the address. there's a high likelihood that addresses in the same city will be similar, though one might include the country and another might not. Having said all that, fuzzy-matching cities to countries is not very straightforward. You may also try to use Google for the address auto-complete -- they know all possible addresses on the Earth and can tell you the country from the street address easily.